# How to remove BOM from an encoded base64 UTF string?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, base64

I have a file encoded in base64 using `openssl base64 -in en -out en1` in a command line in MacOS and I am reading this file using the following code:

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, MConst.BASE_DIR, "en1"));
var b1 = Convert.FromBase64String(fileContent);
var str1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b1);
```

The string I am getting has a `?` before the actual file content. I am not sure what's causing this, any help will be appreciated.

Example Input:

```
import pandas
import json
```

Encoded file example:

```
77u/DQppbXBvcnQgY29ubmVjdG9yX2FwaQ0KaW1wb3J0IGpzb24NCg0K
```

Output based on the C# code:

```
?import pandas
import json
```

Comment: Can you give an example input and output?

Comment: @gunr2171 done, let me know if that doesn't satisfy what you want.

Comment: What's an example of `fileContent`, which should be a base64 encoded value?

Comment: Are you sure you should be using UTF8 for the encoding, not ASCII? https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Base64

Comment: 77u is the byte order marker, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59882396/7329832

Comment: @gunr2171 actually, no adding `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b1);` add `???` instead of `?`

Comment: @jps should the `encoding.utf8`take care of that, according to that post. Am i missing something?

Comment: Documentation says you should trim the BOM using `TrimStart`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.getstring?view=net-6.0

Comment: @qwerty when I decode the string to utf-8 on base64decode.org or with node.js there is no '?' in the output. The BOM is an invisible zero-space character. I have no idea why it is different on C#.

Comment: @jps yes I observed the same. It's bumming me out lol.

Comment: @Charlieface TrimStart expects a particular string to Trim, correct? Will the encoding always have that specific string I have mentioned in my question?

Comment: Of course it could be different. C# is *documented* to decode the BOM into the string, other decoders do not. For example, SQL Server also shows the BOM https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e33a7334ad7e09a15f5a70934f9c0104 `TrimStart` without any parameters removes all whitespace, and removes the BOM. It's reasonably efficient if it's not there (it will not create a new string unnecessarily). I don't know what your data will have, I don't have X-ray vision. I suggest you check what you have.

Comment: @Charlieface Much appreciated! Yeah, for some reason C# isn't able to. What I meant by the specific string was that will BOM always be a `77u/`. Didn't expect you to foresee what my string data will look like. 

If you would like to post that as your answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom) This should give you a button to click above to accept

Comment: @Charlieface it answers my question about how the BOMs could be different. Unfortunately, the question of how to decode a UTF-8 string in C# with BOM still persists.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/how-to-convert-utf-8-byte-to-string. `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` and then strip the BOM. Or you can just check the first three bytes and skip them. Also if you use `Encoding.UTF8` as opposed to `Encoding.ASCII` it at least converts the BOM correctly into `0xFEFF`. Incidentally when I tested it `TrimStart` did not remove it unless you use `TrimStart((char)0xFEFF)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when you read UTF (with BOM) from a text file, the decoding is handled for you behind the scene. For example, both of the following lines will read UTF text correctly regardless of whether or not the text file has a BOM:

```
File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8);
File.ReadAllText(path); // UTF8 is the default.
```

The problem is that you're dealing with UTF text that has been encoded to a Base64 string. So, `ReadAllText()` can no longer handle the BOM for you. You can either do it yourself by (checking and) removing the first 3 bytes from the byte array or delegate that job to a StreamReader, [which is exactly what `ReadAllText()` does](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,827):

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fileContent);
string finalString = null;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms))  // Or:
// using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    finalString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
// Proceed to using finalString.
```